# problem with my Local HttpServer with SSL encryption, encryption not activated

Tags: android

First, I tried to set up a HTTP server without encryption. That worked. Next, I want to add SSL encryption in order to secure the connection. So understand that I need a certificate for this.

I make use of `sun.net.HttpsServer`:

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsConfigurator;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

private static final String KEYSTORE_PASSWORD = "pass_store";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "pass_key";
private int port = 5000;
private HttpServer mHttpServer = null;
private HttpExchange mHttpExchange=null;
private InetSocketAddress isa=null;
private Socket serverSocket =null;
private Config config;
private HttpsServer mHttpsServer = null;
```

My code:

```java
private SSLContext getSslContext() throws Exception {
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    kmf.init(ks, KEY_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
    tmf.init(ks);
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
    return sslContext;
}

private void startHTTPServer() {

    try {
        isa = new InetSocketAddress(port);
        mHttpsServer = HttpsServer.create(isa, 0);
        SSLContext sslContext = getSslContext();
        mHttpsServer.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext));
        mHttpsServer.createContext("/", rootHandler);
        mHttpsServer.createContext("/index", rootHandler);

        mHttpsServer.start(); //startServer server;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private void sendResponse(HttpExchange httpExchange, String responseText) {
    try {
        //httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, (long) responseText.length());
        byte[] bs = responseText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, bs.length);
        OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        os.write(bs);

        // OutputStream os = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        // os.write(responseText.getBytes());
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private HttpHandler rootHandler = new HttpHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        if (httpExchange.getRequestMethod().equals("GET")) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(
                    config.mypreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sendResponse(httpExchange, "" + Config.messageCheckServerAvailable + ":" + sharedPref.getString(config.keyPrefs_universID, null));
        }
    }
};
```

SSL encryption requires a certificate created using the keytool in order to authenticate clients . How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: You should generally avoid using classes from `com.sun` packages, it's considered bad practice. I recommend you to change your server implementation.

Comment: If you have a solution, i'm interrested?

Comment: I don't know whether there is an Android-specific solution, but you might check out something like https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/ or http://sparkjava.com/. They are widely used and I *guess* they do also work on Android. You can see the documentation on how to set up the SSL encryption on your own.

Comment: You may want to check this out to understand the background: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/faq-sun-packages.html